# Why does appending text to the end of each line replaces the first characters instead?

Tags: carriage-return

I searched everywhere but I haven't seen anyone have the same issue, yet alone a solution to this. I am trying to add text at the end of each line like so:

```
"Name1";"2913"
"Name2";"2914"
```

into:

```
"Name1";"2913";""
"Name2";"2914";""
```

I have tried it with sed, awk(with gsub) and pearl commands but each time instead of adding the ;"" to the end of each line it just replaces the first 3 characters of each line with it:

```
"Name1";"2913"
```

becomes

```
;""me1";"2913"
```

It is not limited to just ;"" it happends with anything i try to add at the end of the line.
code i tried:

```
cat list | sed 's/$/;""/'
cat list | awk '{gsub(/$/,";\"\"")}1'
```

each with the same outcome of:

```
;""me1";"2913"
;""me2";"2914"
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like OP may have control M characters in OP's Input_file in that case could you please try following.

```
awk -v s1="\"" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(/\r/,"");$(NF+1)=s1 s1} 1'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** With `sed`:

```
sed 's/\r//g;s/$/;""/' Input_file
```

***Suggestions for OP's code:***

- We need not to use `cat` with `awk` or `sed` they are capable of reading Input_file by themselves.
- You could have control M characters in your file so you could remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file` OR directly run commands mentioned above to get rid of the carriage returns and get your output too.